# Kubernetes - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, memory, kubernetes, containers

I know this is something very common and there are so many numbers of blogs & forums created which help to solve this problem. Posting this question here after running through all those articles with no luck. Kindly advise.

The `OOM unable to create new native thread` is happening for all the Pods that are running on the Worker node.

We have got Applications running on `Java 1.8.0_212` with no memory request/limit and with no `-Xmx` settings.

```
/ #java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize
    uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 528482304                           {product}
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 8434745344                          {product}
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.12.0) (Alpine 8.212.04-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

The Kubernetes worker is running on `32G` of RAM and since we are not letting the JVM to be aware of the Container world, 1/4 of Worker's RAM is used for JVM's heap size.

Here is the output of `ulimit` on the Worker node for the root user(since all the containers are running as a root user on the node)

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 128613
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 128613
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Earlier We thought the issue is due to the PIDs getting exhausted on the Host, and thus all the Applications running on the Host are running out of threads, but we were wrong

```
# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/kubepods.slice/pids.max
131072
# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/kubepods.slice/pids.current
2905
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
257226
# cat /proc/loadavg
1.42 1.27 1.23 4/3426 18467
```

From the output above you can see, we do have enough threads available on the Host. And we have enough free memory.

```
# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             31           1          22           1           7          27
Swap:             0           0           0

# grep Slab /proc/meminfo
Slab:            2830984 kB

# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.failcnt
0
```

Since it is affecting across all the JVMs running on the host, we know something on the Host is not right which is creating this threads exhaustion, unable to find out what that is. Please share your inputs, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after a long time of debugging and searching, we found one of our applications created over 30k threads in a short time. It exhausted all of pids on the host. After we limit the total pids one pod can use, everything returned normal.

Reference:
https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/265
https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-node/20190129-pid-limiting.md#summary